# FileMaker MissingFunction

Tags: filemaker, method-missing

```
Set Variable [$Write; Value: <Function Missing>("filepath";$inputedText)]
```

I'm trying to determine what the missing function is. I'm trying to write data to an external file with this script, and this is one line of code from the script. I can't post the rest of the code for security reasons. Any direction as to what the missing function would be would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really need to provide more details. Functions don't go missing just like that. What exactly did you do to get to this point? For example, did you import the script from another file? If so, there may be a custom function defined in the source file, which you need to import as well - see: http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/fmpa_custom.24.6.html#1041172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **< Function Missing>** message means that this code was written with the expectation that a now-missing plugin would be present. To resolve this, you'll need to determine which plugin this is, and install this on your development machine (and likely on all machines needing to use this script, unless you choose to write this to execute as a PSOS script running on the server).

My best guess based on functionality and the arguments being passed is that the missing plugin may be the [Monkeybread Plugin](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/filemaker/).

Comment: I disagree with down-vote, as this is the most probable answer. I think, the plugin could be any, does not have to be Monkeybread.

Comment: vote up for mentioning plugins, but it's a diff plug in than mentioned

Comment: I would still flag it as an answer as it pushed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `Write To File` function in `ScriptMaster`